# Embedded Power BI - Enterprise Gateway Support

Tags: powerbi

1. Does Embedded Power BI support Enterprise Gateway connection to connect to On-Prem database.  So far, I have my solution working with DB replicated in cloud, however would skip that step if I could.
2. If yes, what is the connection string for Enterprise Gateway Connection, so I can update my DataSets after uploading PBIX file inside the Workspaces.

Comment: Looking at the code and how it is behaving.  I don't think this is supported yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't yet support the enterprise gateway. It is in the works.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the reply and good to know it is in the pipeline. Do you know general timeline for this feature - near future, next year etc.?

Comment: Not exact timelines yet but we know that it is important.